# What does 他人の目にも楽しく mean?

Tags: grammar

> 幸福というものについて、これだといい切れる考えはまだ私も持っていないが、私は「会社での仕事も楽しく、家庭での生活も楽しい、つまり一日二十四時間を楽しく過ごすこと」が幸福だと思っている。言葉はすこぶる（注6）平凡だが、この内容は非凡だと自負している（注7）。それと、自分の幸福な状態が「**他人の目にも楽しく、心も楽しませ**る」ものでありたいとも私は思う。

What does "他人の目にも楽しく" mean? I guess に is indicating a position here, so 目にも楽しく means "being happy even in others's eyes", but I am unsure about my guess.

Answer (score 1):

The 楽しく in 他人の目にも**楽しく** refers not exactly to the subject's happiness as *being happy* would. It should be a variant of [目を楽しませる](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9B%AE%E3%82%92%E6%A5%BD%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B), literally meaning *pleasing (someone's) eyes* or *visually enjoyable*.

So it says that 自分の幸福な状態 provides satisfaction/joy to others visually and mentally.

Comment: what does に mean in that sentence? can you provide more useage of に like this?

Comment: @CN.hitori It is *to*. Thinking 楽しい=happy would make it difficult to understand. It is *pleasant **to***.